# In CakePHP, beforeRender in the AppController is saving to database twice

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP, so I'm still learning a lot of the behaviors and everything. One I'm struggling to find a solution to is the fact that I have a code in the AppController using beforeRender. The code saves the user's ID, their IP address, and the current time of the page load to the database in order to record activity.

I'm getting a rather curious result, and though I've looked around for an answer I haven't been able to find it. Upon loading a page that is controlled by another controller (in this case, the UserController), it saves the data to the database as well as an exact duplicate.

Right now I have just a handful of pages. The main index page, the login page, the register page, the user profile page, and the user settings page. Everything but the index page is controlled in the UserController, but I have a redirect from the login and register pages so their URLs are /login instead of /users/login. Interestingly, the duplicates aren't created on the login or register pages-- just the profile and settings page.

I had originally placed the code in beforeFilter, and I got 3 copies of the same data instead of 2. I've also tried it in afterFilter but I still got 2 copies.

I should mention, the three fields that I am updating are not located in the Users table in the database- they have their own table 'Activities'.

This is my beforeRender code in the AppController:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if ($user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->loadModel('Activity');
        $data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $data['Activity']['user_ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();
        $data['Activity']['user_id'] = $data['User']['id'];
        $data['Activity']['last_activity'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->Activity->save($data);
    }
}
```

Per request, this is the controller action for the Profile page, one of the ones causing the duplicates:

```
public function profile($id = null) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('User not found'));
        }
        $user = $this->User->findById($id);
        if (!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('User not found'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
        $this->set('title_for_layout', $user['User']['screenname'] . "'s" . ' ' . 'Profile');
    }
```

And the view for the profile page (it's mostly basic HTML):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('profile');  ?>

<h2><?php echo h($user['User']['screenname']); ?></h2>

<center><table cellpadding="6">
<tr><center>
    <td><center><div class="ha_image"></div>
    </td>
    <td><center><h4>User Information</h4>
    <div class="user_info">
        <table class="">
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Member Type
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    --
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Member Since
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    <?php echo date('M jS, Y', strtotime($user['User']['created'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Last Active
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    <?php echo date('M j, Y h:i A', strtotime($user['User']['last_active'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="laststats_names">
                    Status
                </td>
                <td class="laststats_stats">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Totals
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    --
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Forum Posts
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    --
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="stats_names">
                    Achievements
                </td>
                <td class="stats_stats">
                    --
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="laststats_names">
                    Quests Done
                </td>
                <td class="laststats_stats">
                    --
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: This doesn't pertain to the dupe problem, but don't use `$this->request->data` for your activities because it may contain POST data. So if one of your pages POSTs a form, there will be lots of data in `$this->request->data` that may cause problems when saving to your `activities` table.  Just use `$data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');` and so on. And save via `$this->Activity->save($data);`

Comment: re: dupes : please post the controller & view code for one of the offending actions.  Are you calling `requestAction()` anywhere?

Comment: @Costa, I changed the activities to just $data as you said, and I also updated the post with the controller and view of the profile page, which is one of the two causing the duplicates.

Comment: Seems fine to me. You sure you don't have similar code in your other callbacks? Check AppController and your controller.

Comment: I'm fairly positive... 'activity' isn't used at all in my UserController, and my AppController just has a couple of other functions that don't even go near 'activity'. Is there perhaps a better place than AppController to put a function I want to happen on every page?

Comment: What's your exact CakePHP version? Also have you checked whether the callbacks are actually triggered more than once, for example by putting some debug output in it? If they _are_ triggered multiple times, and actually in _one and the same_ request, try an exception and check the stack trace to find out from where it's actually triggered: `$e = new Exception(); pr($e->getTraceAsString());`

Comment: I actually just figured out the problem. My default layout was trying to find the favicon.ico image and was unable to do so, so it was loading the page as well as a hidden 404 image not found error, causing the double logs. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you have something like

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

in your controller. When the index page load, the beforeRender function is called again.